# IronRuby error: Microsoft.Scripting.Actions.Calls.OverloadInfo (trying to port MEF)

Tags: mef, ironruby

I'm trying to upgrade some 4 year old code from a blog post that allows IronRuby to import/export MEF parts.

The code is at: https://github.com/JogoShugh/IronRubyMef

Unfortunately, I get this error when attempting to run:

```
Method not found: 'Microsoft.Scripting.Actions.Calls.OverloadInfo[] 
Microsoft.Scripting.Actions.Calls.ReflectionOverloadInfo.CreateArray
(System.Reflection.MemberInfo[])
```

I only found one reference to this on the IronRuby forum, and sent another note. But, does anyone else have any idea what could cause this?

Thank you

Answer (score 3):

That error is normally caused when calling Object.new from a ruby script. Which should be working of course, IronRuby 1.1.3 seems to come with a bug where if you do Object.methods it actually lists :new but it fails on invocation.

The fix is somewhat simple, just prepend this to your Ruby program initialization, before any requires call:

```
class System::Object
  def initialize
  end
end

requires 'some/module'

# Rest of your code...
```

Now, when any script calls Object.new, it'll work correctly.I wrote a post about this issue: http://marcel.bowlitz.com/continuous-integration/custom-resources-in-visual-studio-test-projects
**UPDATE:** IronRuby 1.1.4 (found in http://github.com/IronLanguages/main) fixes this issue. You have checkout the code and build.

Comment: I'm responding to your comment, in hopes you read the update to the answer.

Comment: IronRuby 1.1.4 seems to have been revoked: https://www.nuget.org/packages/IronRuby/ You have to build it manually if you want/need this fix. :(